# How to avoid answering "No problem" when receiving thanks?

Tags: word-choice

I mostly say "no problem" when I do something and people thank me. I read somewhere that this is not always correct as it shows like I spent no effort which is not always the case and sometimes it's very the opposite. I was advised I should be saying "always welcome" and "glad to help". But it still not appropriate in some cases (for example, when it's the boss who thanks me I don't think I should be saying that). What could be other possible answers in such situation? The more variants the better because I feel like I am reusing the same sentences over and over.

Comment: It's fine with me if you want to ask for other ways to say this, but I strongly disagree with the assertion that it's "not always correct." Only an annoying pendant would misconstrue a polite and idiomatic response as "inaccurate" because it didn't truly reflect the amount of effort expended.

Comment: @J.R. I think the advice being given there might be that if you continually say this, people might take your help for granted a bit (so it's not that the English is wrong, but that it might end up undermining you a bit/ending with you being taken for granted).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+was+my+pleasure%2Cno+problem%2Cyou+are+welcome%2Cmy+pleasure&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20was%20my%20pleasure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20are%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20pleasure%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Khan - I don't know how much that ngram really pertains to this. Those "no problem" hits are riddled with results that don't pertain to this discussion, such as: _I hope there is no problem; I have no problem with that; there seems to be no problem; if you had just moved out, we would have no problem; a value of 0 indicates no problem; if no problem exists, then there is no problem to fix; Dr. Doyle had no problem eating and talking at the same time; the Reformation had no problem of nature and grace; no problem is scientifically settled by abandoning one suggested solution;_ and so forth.